# Por qué 2 elevado a n el resultado está en bytes?

Tags: unidades-de-medición

Es una duda un poco tonta pero nunca me lo había preguntado hasta ahora. Yo entiendo que si tenemos por ejemplo 2^2, donde el exponente indica el nº de bits, eso son 4 números que podemos expresar con 2 bits. Y sabemos que 8 bits es un byte, hasta ahí todo correcto. Mi duda surge en por qué si yo tengo 2^10, donde 10 es el número de bits, por qué eso equivale a 1024KiB(en BYTES) y no por ejemplo equivale a 1024 Bits. No entiendo esa "conversión" de que yo tenga un 2 elevado a un número de bits y que el resultado de hacer 2 elevado a ese número salga algo que está en BYTES. Gracias de antemano

Comment: hay un error de conversion de tipos.. en el caso de 2 a la 10, no estaras hablando de bytes?

Comment: Es que 2^n equivale al valor que tendrá el bit n-1 (2^0=1, 2^1=2, 2^2=4...etc)

Comment: @ArnauCastellví Eso no tiene sentido porque empiezas con el bit "-1"...

Comment: @gbianchi si si, son 2^10 bytes, pero yo iba al hecho de que el exponente en este caso en concreto, indica el número de bits, y no entiendo por qué el resultado está en bytes. Me explico, tenemos un bus de direcciones físicas de 10 bits, por tanto en esa memoria física podremos direccionar 2^10 Bytes, ahi voy, por qué bytes y no 2^10 bits.

Comment: @SJuan76 Estoy dando a entender que empiezo a contar los bits por 1, no por 0, o sea, que el lsb es el 1.

Comment: @ArnauCastellví Si el primer valor de `n` es 0, entonces el `bit n-1` será `-1`...

Comment: Esa equivalencia de2^n volviéndose mágicamente bytes no es real. Necesitas revisar la definición de byte porque estás confundiendo el maíz con la mazorca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 2^2, donde el exponente indica el nº de bits

El exponente no "indica" el número de bits. 2<sup>2</sup> es un número, que se puede expresar como *2<sup>2</sup>*, como *4*, como *5 - 1*, como *raíz cuadrada de 16*, etc.

Ahora, si tienes todas las variaciones con repetición de `n` elementos tomados de `k` símbolos distintos, tienes *k<sup>n</sup>* elementos. Cuando trabajamos con sistemas binarios (dos símbolos distintos), `k` es 2.

Así, 10 bits te dan *2<sup>10</sup>* o *1024* variaciones con repetición distintas. Eso es todo.

O, puesto de otra forma, necesitas 10 bits para representar 1024 elementos distintos.

Ahora bien, puedes usar esos 10 bits -> 1024 valores para identificar **1024 elementos distintos** (normalmente si trabajamos con memoria, **por su posición**).

Por convención, cuando trabajamos con ese número tenemos un prefijo estándar para reemplazarlo, el Ki. Si estamos haciendo referencia a un Ki de bytes, tenemos un KiB(yte). Si es de bits, tenemos un Kib(it). Si son gatos, un KiC(at). Pero el *1024*, en la forma que sea, es solo un número.

Es exactamente igual como el sistema métrico decimal; *deca-* solo significa 10, sean litros, kilos o metros. Luego está que para codificar el número 10 necesitas 2 dígitos decimales, pero eso no está relacionado.

En el caso digital, resulta que 10 bits dan 1024 que es razonablemente cercano a un número "redondo" en el sistema decimal, lo cual es útil; 2<sup>10</sup> aprox. igual a *10<sup>3</sup>*

Así que si tengo 32 bits de direccionamiento tengo cerca de *10<sup>3</sup> x 10<sup>3</sup> x 10<sup>3</sup> x 4* (los dos bits que sobran) o *4 x 10<sup>9</sup>* posibles direcciones.

Comment: vale entiendo lo que dices, voy a refinar ahora mi pregunta. Estamos de acuerdo en que si hacemos 2^10 nos sale 1024, un número como tu dices, pero por qué cuando estamos en el campo de la informática o números binarios, como quieras, por qué tomamos que 2^10 es 1KiB(yte), y no por ej 1 kibi bit

Comment: Por definición, se dijo que la únidad mínima a la que se puede hacer direccionamiento es el byte. Dejando aparte restricciones de HW (es mucho más lento transmitir bytes de uno en uno que un grupo en paralelo), si quieres hacer un direccionamiento a cada bit necesitas 3 bits de direccionamiento más. Y no es que un bit tenga mucha información por si solo.

Comment: o sea es como que nos movemos de byte en byte por las direcciones y no de bit en bit?

Comment: Y no, no cambies la pregunta para cambiar una cosa distinta. Puedes **refinarla**, pero no cambiar lo que se pregunta. Al hacerlo invalidas las respuestas ya existentes, y si te sale una diferente siempre puedes crear una pregunta distinta.

Comment: Sí. Conceptualmente puedes tener un Kibit (quitas los tres últimos bits de la dirección para obtener el byte y los usas para obtener el bit dentro del byte), pero nadie usa eso.

Comment: los tres últimos bits por qué?

Comment: 2^3 = 8, y hay 8 bits en un byte.

Comment: vaale vaale, para finalizar la pregunta y a ver si lo he entendido: entonces en este campo de la informática, si me dan por ejemplo, una memoria con direcciones de 5 bits, entonces yo lo que decir es que la capacidad en bytes(de la memoria) será de 2 elevado a 5 en este caso no?

Comment: La capacidad será 2^5 de lo que se esté direccionando (podría ser que tu chip trabaje con *words*, por ejemplo). Lo que se usa para programar son bytes, pero el HW cada vez se hace más paralelo para aumentar la velocidad de transmisión de datos.

Comment: Aquel chico me confundió, se supone que * 8 bits es 1 byte y * 1kb es 1024 byte, Entonces no sé porque dice que 10 bits es **2^10** byte en 1kb.

Comment: Cool, sólo (sólo) que no hay decakilos, posiblemente hay decagramos o kilogramos :P

Answer (score 1):

2^n equivale al valor que tendrá el bit n+1 (contando los bits a partir de 1)

Por ej. 2^0=1 (bit 1), 2^1=2 (bit 2), 2^2=4 (bit 3)...etc

De manera que 2^10 = el valor del bit 11 = 1024.

También se podría decir que 2^n es el valor máximo+1 de un numero de n bits.
Por ej. 2^10 corresponde al valor máximo+1 de un numero de 10 bits: 1023.

EDIT: Creo que tu problema, es el concepto de KB y KiB:
Cuando se habla de capacidad, se usa 2^n, grupos de 1024 Bytes (KiB,MiB...)
Cuando se habla de velocidades, se usa 10^n, grupos de 1000 bits (Kb/s,Mb/s...)
Para que los números parezcan mayores, las empresas usan la unidad KB, usando grupos de 1000 Bytes.
Por ejemplo, un disco duro etiquetado como 1TB, realmente son 10^12 Bytes, que corresponden a 0,91TiB.

Resumiendo:

1KiB=1024B (2^10)
1KB=1000B (10^3)
1Kb=1000b = 1KB/8 = 0,125KB = 0,122KiB